# Keep 4 columns in a horizontal row

Tags: html, css

I used W3 row containers for keep 4 columns in a row. But when add an image , the image doesn't fit with the container and unable to fix the height of the container. I have added the zoom option when hovering on the image. Is that good w3 containers or are there any best method?

```
.item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}


<div class="w3-row" style="margin-left:2%;">
  <div class="w3-col w3-green w3-container" style="width:25%">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="../Images/stock-vector-romantic-pink-heart-background-vector-illustration-for-holiday-design-many-flying-hearts-on-white-370450901.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-col w3-blue w3-container" style="width:2%">
    <p>30%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-dark-grey w3-container" style="width:20%">
    <p>35%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-blue w3-container" style="width:2%">
    <p>30%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-blue w3-container" style="width:25%">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="../Images/stock-vector-romantic-pink-heart-background-vector-illustration-for-holiday-design-many-flying-hearts-on-white-370450901.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-blue w3-container" style="width:2%">
    <p>30%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-purple w3-container" style="width:20%">
    <p>10%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's is quite a small zoom. It only works as an effect. It doesn't work to practically view the image better.

Comment: I want to know specially is there any way that fit the image to the container?

Comment: @IreshaShyamean you want those in one row?

Comment: Are you sure it's a row and not a column!

Comment: @DanielH Yes i want 4 columns in one row

Comment: is this what your page looks like? looks like 4 columns in a row to me. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNyWej

Comment: This feels too similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718649/keep-4-divs-in-a-horizontal-row?rq=1)...

Comment: @JamesDouglas yes ofcourse. I want the solution for that.

Comment: @MichaelCoker YES. But the image doesn't fit with the container. Container displays separately as "Green" color

Comment: @IreshaShyamean you shouldn't re-ask a question, just editing it is enough for other people to notice.

Comment: @JamesDouglas But when edit, nobody answered. So I asked it. Now also you don't say a solution. Only advising about re-asking.

Comment: @IreshaShyamean I would use a table in this instance, but that might be just me...

Comment: @IreshaShyamean there are three answers, do none of them work?

Comment: @JamesDouglas not yet. But I am trying

Comment: @IreshaShyamean is there any way of notifying the answerers that their suggestions didn't work? I forget where new users are able to comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fit image to container, use bootstrap class thumbnail inside block/cell and use image inside a div tag which have thumbnail class. And then use image tag with bootstrap class img-responsive.
It will be better, if you will use image with good aspect ratio according to its container/cell.

Please first read about above mention classes and then use.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the grid width (ex: s1 s2 s3 ... up to s12 for small screen size)

more info you should read here:

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_grid.asp

To fit img inside container you could do this:

```
.w3-col {
  height: 75px;
}

img{
  height: 75px;
}
```

```css
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.w3-col {
  height: 75px;
}


img{
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-col w3-green w3-container s3 w3-center">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-blue w3-container s3 w3-center">
    <p>30%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-dark-grey w3-container s3 w3-center">
    <p>35%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-blue w3-container s3 w3-center">
    <p>30%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-blue w3-container s3 w3-center">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="100%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-blue w3-container s3 w3-center">
    <p>30%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-purple w3-container s3 w3-center">
    <p>10%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good to work with w3 containers as it gives you a responsive UI by creating sectors in you web page. A good selection I would say. And, you seem to have implemented it all correct.

About the thing with image height, can you try "height: auto" in your image CSS? May be I am not getting at right point!